# How to round a number to the specified upper or lower bond?

Tags: python, integer, rounding, lower-bound, upperbound

I'm working on a data-set on which I have certain values which are needed to be rounded to either lower/upper bound.

eg. if I want the upper bound to be **9** and lower to **3** and we have numbers like -

```
[ 7.453511737983394, 
  8.10917072790058, 
  6.2377799380575, 
  5.225853201122676, 
  4.067932296134156 ]
```

and we want to list to be rounded to either 3 or 9 like -

```
[ 9, 
  9, 
  9, 
  3, 
  3 ]
```

I know we can do that in a good old fashion like iterating in the array and finding the difference and then getting the one which is closest.

my-approach-code:

```
for i in the_list[:]:
    three = abs(3-the_list[i])  
    nine = abs(9-the_list[i])

    if three < nine:
        the_list[i] = three
    else:
        the_list[i] = nine
```

I'm wondering if there is a *quick and dirty* way which is inbuilt in python like:

```
hey_bound = round_the_num(number, bound_1, bound_2)
```

I know that we can `my-approach-code` but I'm pretty much sure that out there this has been implemented in much better way, I tried to find it but had no luck finding it, and here we are.

any guesses or direct links for solution to this will be amazing.

Comment: Can you just check if it's less than or greater than `6` and assign `3` or `9`? More generally, less than or greater than the mean of or your upper and lower bound.

Comment: I'm talking in general here.

Comment: Would the comparing to the mean of upper and lower bound not work for you? I don't think there is a builtin function for this however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**
The best approach in my opinion up to now is using numpy (to avoid "manual" looping) with a simple calculation of the difference arrays between `the_list` and the two bounds (so no expensive multiplication here), to then only conditionally add the one or the other, depending on which is smaller:

```
import numpy as np

the_list = np.array([ 7.453511737983394,
8.10917072790058, 
6.2377799380575, 
5.225853201122676, 
4.067932296134156 ])

dhi = 9 - the_list
dlo = 3 - the_list
idx = dhi + dlo < 0
the_rounded = the_list + np.where(idx, dhi, dlo)
# array([9., 9., 9., 3., 3.])
```

---

I'd apply round function to the offsetless normalized list and scale back and add offset afterwards:

```
import numpy as np

the_list = np.array([ 7.453511737983394,
8.10917072790058, 
6.2377799380575, 
5.225853201122676, 
4.067932296134156 ])

hi = 9
lo = 3
dlt = hi - lo

the_rounded = np.round((the_list - lo)/dlt) * dlt + lo

# [9. 9. 9. 3. 3.]
```

Comment: a quick `timeit` would be awesome

Comment: _quick_ was not enough, as it turned out... - see the comparison answer below

Answer (score 3):

***Timing comparison*** *of available answers*

[image]

My interpretation would be:
From performance point of view you should go with Abhishek Patel or Carles Mitjans for smaller lists.
For lists containing several dozens of values and more, numpy array and then adding conditionally the differences with the smaller absolute values seems to be the fastest solution.

---

Code used for timing comparison:

```
import timeit
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('ggplot')

rep = 5

timings = dict()

for n in range(7):
    print(f'N = 10^{n}')

    N = 10**n
    setup = f'''import numpy as np\nthe_list = np.random.random({N})*6+3\nhi = 9\nlo = 3\ndlt = hi - lo\nmid = (hi + lo) / 2\ndef return_the_num(l, lst, h):\n    return [l if abs(l-x) < abs(h-x) else h for x in lst]'''

    fct = 'np.round((the_list - lo)/dlt) * dlt + lo'
    t = timeit.Timer(fct, setup=setup)
    timings['SpghttCd_np'] = timings.get('SpghttCd_np', []) + [np.min(t.repeat(repeat=rep, number=1))]

    fct = 'return_the_num(3, the_list, 9)'
    t = timeit.Timer(fct, setup=setup)
    timings['Austin'] = timings.get('Austin', []) + [np.min(t.repeat(repeat=rep, number=1))]

    fct = '[(lo, hi)[mid < v] for v in the_list]'
    t = timeit.Timer(fct, setup=setup)
    timings['SpghttCd_lc'] = timings.get('SpghttCd_lc', []) + [np.min(t.repeat(repeat=rep, number=1))]

    setup += '\nround_the_num = lambda list, upper, lower: [upper if x > (upper + lower) / 2 else lower for x in list]'
    fct = 'round_the_num(the_list, 9, 3)'
    t = timeit.Timer(fct, setup=setup)
    timings['Carles Mitjans'] = timings.get('Carles Mitjans', []) + [np.min(t.repeat(repeat=rep, number=1))]

    setup += '\nupper_lower_bound_list=[3,9]'
    fct = '[min(upper_lower_bound_list, key=lambda x:abs(x-myNumber)) for myNumber in the_list]'
    t = timeit.Timer(fct, setup=setup)
    timings['mad_'] = timings.get('mad_', []) + [np.min(t.repeat(repeat=rep, number=1))]

    setup += '\ndef return_bound(x, l, h):\n    low = abs(x - l)\n    high = abs(x - h)\n    if low < high:\n        return l\n    else:\n        return h'
    fct = '[return_bound(x, 3, 9) for x in the_list]'
    t = timeit.Timer(fct, setup=setup)
    timings["Scratch'N'Purr"] = timings.get("Scratch'N'Purr", []) + [np.min(t.repeat(repeat=rep, number=1))]

    setup += '\ndef round_the_list(list, bound_1, bound_2):\n\tmid = (bound_1+bound_2)/2\n\tfor i in range(len(list)):\n\t\tif list[i] > mid:\n\t\t\tlist[i] = bound_2\n\t\telse:\n\t\t\tlist[i] = bound_1'
    fct = 'round_the_list(the_list, 3, 9)'
    t = timeit.Timer(fct, setup=setup)
    timings["Abhishek Patel"] = timings.get("Abhishek Patel", []) + [np.min(t.repeat(repeat=rep, number=1))]

    fct = 'dhi = 9 - the_list\ndlo = 3 - the_list\nidx = dhi + dlo < 0\nthe_list + np.where(idx, dhi, dlo)'
    t = timeit.Timer(fct, setup=setup)
    timings["SpghttCd_where"] = timings.get("SpghttCd_where", []) + [np.min(t.repeat(repeat=rep, number=1))]

print('done')

df = pd.DataFrame(timings, 10**np.arange(n+1))
ax = df.plot(logx=True, logy=True)
ax.set_xlabel('length of the list')
ax.set_ylabel('seconds to run')
ax.get_lines()[-1].set_c('g')
plt.legend()
print(df)
```

Comment: this is amazing, thank you so much for you efforts, a quick question: Where i can learn about scale/offset calculation methods or as such array manipulation and transversing techniques? 

or is this just experience?

Comment: Well, regarding the array manipulation and general calculation methods I definitely would recommend to have a look at `numpy`, as it's designed to give mathematical power to python. For more algorithms based on this fundament (e.g. for more sophisticated curve fitting, filtering or signal analysis in general) `scipy` would be the next address. But in terms of the actual scale/offset thing here, I think this is just a matter of experience or better habit. If you often have to think in terms of offset and slope of characteristics, you'll probably associate a question like yours with these.

Comment: "***If you often have to think in terms of offset and slope of characteristics, you'll probably associate a question like yours with these.*** " - point noted ! danke schoen

Comment: what's up with *where* one?

Comment: Don't understand the question, sorry

Comment: I see that you have added a new curve to the graph with a black line depiction, ***Spghtt_where*** what does it mean?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't uodate the code section. I'll do that asap. It's basically still using numpy but without multiplication, but more like the threshold approaches based on mean of hi and lo bound.

Comment: alright, it'll be better if you post it as another answer and not merge it with this answer like you posted two answers previously. separately, thanks again for the efforts !

Comment: No, wait: my fault. I'll update the code here but this for showing how timing was made only anyway. The code is already there as the last edit in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can generalize by finding the midpoint, and checking which side of the midpoint each number in the list is on

```
def round_the_list(list, bound_1, bound_2):
  mid = (bound_1+bound_2)/2
  for i in range(len(list)):
        if list[i] > mid:         # or >= depending on your rounding decision
            list[i] = bound_2
        else:
            list[i] = bound_1
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could write a function and use it in a list comprehension.

```
def return_bound(x, l, h):
    low = abs(x - l)
    high = abs(x - h)
    if low < high:
        return l
    else:
        return h
```

Test:

```
>>> mylist = [7.453511737983394, 8.10917072790058, 6.2377799380575, 5.225853201122676, 4.067932296134156]
>>> [return_bound(x, 3, 9) for x in mylist]
[9, 9, 9, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

A one liner list comprehension using inbuilt `min` function by modifying the key argument to look for an absolute difference

```
upper_lower_bound_list=[3,9]
myNumberlist=[ 7.453511737983394, 
8.10917072790058, 
6.2377799380575, 
5.225853201122676, 
4.067932296134156 ]
```

List comprehension

```
[min(upper_lower_bound_list, key=lambda x:abs(x-myNumber)) for myNumber in myNumberlist]
```

**Output**

```
[9, 9, 9, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using list comprehensions and lambda functions:

```
round_the_num = lambda list, upper, lower: [upper if x > (upper + lower) / 2 else lower for x in list]

round_the_num(l, 9, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom function that does a list-comprehension, like:

```
lst = [ 7.453511737983394, 
  8.10917072790058, 
  6.2377799380575, 
  5.225853201122676, 
  4.067932296134156 ]

def return_the_num(l, lst, h): 
    return [l if abs(l-x) < abs(h-x) else h for x in lst]

print(return_the_num(3, lst, 9))
# [9, 9, 9, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

I really like @AbhishekPatel's idea about comparing against the mid point. But I'd put it into a LC using the result as an index for a bounds tuple:

```
the_list = [ 7.453511737983394,
8.10917072790058, 
6.2377799380575, 
5.225853201122676, 
4.067932296134156 ]

hi = 9
lo = 3
mid = (hi + lo) / 2

[(lo, hi)[mid < v] for v in the_list]
# [9, 9, 9, 3, 3]
```

---

... but this is over 15 times slower than the numpy approach.
However, this here can handle numbers bigger than `hi` or lower than `lo`.
... but this again only for a 100000 entry list. In case of the original list posted by OP the two variants are very close together...